# Converting a string to a date in a different language

Tags: excel, string, vba, date

I have an excel file of which I need to convert a string into a date. The string is written in dutch, so "15 juli 2018", instead of "15 july 2018". My excel is in english. I know that Excel has many date formats built in, but it doesn't recognize the dutch string as a date. So my problem is that the original string is in a different language. I can't just change my system's language settings because my code is supposed to work on other systems as well.

I'd love to hear any ideas.

Comment: Where is this Excel sheet coming from?  Why is the date being entered as a string instead of as a date?  If you have dirty data, you will need to clean it, probably with some kind of translation matrix.  But it should be entered as a date to begin with.

Comment: If you can't clean it up to get the underlying info to be a date entry, it might be quickest to just create a table of months in Dutch, then English, use `MID()` with a `VLOOKUP()` or so.  What have you tried?

Comment: It's business stuff, I have no control over what they are sending me. Thank you for your advice, I'll try it out!

Comment: There is some thing in the text function that deals with different languages. https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html

Answer (score 0):

With string data in **E1**, in **F1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(E1,FIND(" ",E1)) & VLOOKUP(MID(E1,FIND(" ",E1)+1,FIND(" ",E1,FIND(" ",E1)+1)-(FIND(" ",E1)+1)),I:J,2) & " " & RIGHT(E1,4))
```

[image]

This uses a small Dutch-to-English translation table in cols **I** and **J**

Answer (score 0):

this quick sub will do it in place.  select your dates and run the code:

```
Sub dutchtoeng()
Dim mArr()
mArr = Array("januari", "january", "februari", "february", "maart", "march", "april", "april", "mei", "may", "juni", "june", "juli", "july", "augustus", "august", "september", "september", "oktober", "october", "november", "november", "december", "december")
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(mArr) To UBound(mArr) Step 2
    Selection.Replace mArr(i), mArr(i + 1)
Next i

End Sub
```